# unix shell file parsing

Tags: shell, parsing, unix, text-files

I need to find the shortest solution for

I have a file with lines:

> str \t numbers \t str

I need to output 10 most popular number values

for instance with input:

```
qwqe    128.10.189.128  wwewe
wwewe   228.74.165.218  tssht
dgerg   15.46.11.247    cvbcb
ddfdfdf 205.219.171.189 ggghg
sds 228.5.220.225   ggbg
hg  110.139.130.107 vb
asd 130.139.130.107 vggh
sdsd    66.207.133.81   gff
q   13.26.210.115   f
ggsgfgdfzgg 42.186.57.170   ffdd
dfdf    196.246.43.169  dfdf
sdsd    228.5.220.225   ggsdg
asd 130.139.130.107 vggh
sdsd    66.207.133.81   f
sds 228.5.220.225   ggbg
sdsd    66.207.133.81   gff
sds 228.5.220.225   ggbg
asd 130.139.130.107 vggh
asd 130.139.130.107 vggh
asd 130.139.130.107 vggh
sdsd    66.207.133.81   gff
sdsd    66.207.133.81   gff
sdsd    66.207.200.81   gff
```

the expected output is:

```
66.207.133.81
130.139.130.107    
228.5.220.225
66.207.200.81
42.186.57.170
228.74.165.218
205.219.171.189
196.246.43.169
15.46.11.247
```

I can do this with this sequence of commands:

```
cut -d $'\t' -f2 file.txt|sort|uniq -c|sort -r|head|cut -c6-
```

but this seems complicated and I am not sure it is the shortest way to do it

Comment: That's how I usually do it. BTW, TAB is the default delimiter with `cut`, so you can leave out the `-d` option.

Comment: Your solution highlights the beauty of the Unix command-line philosophy, programs that do 1 thing well, can be connected with each other thru pipes and that don't emit extraneous information that requires extra processing to remove (for instance the DOS dir command ;-) ). You could probably do this in awk or perl with fewer characters, but it would be harder for someone else to maintain; these commands spell out exactly what they are doing. (I think your 2nd sort should be `sort -rn`, right?) . Good luck.

Comment: I started writing an answer for doing this in awk, but .. well, it's *not* fewer characters, and it's just not as short and elegant. I should point out that `$'\t'` notation requires bash or ksh or other advanced shells -- some stock Bourne shells may not use it, so something like `cut -d "\`printf '\t'\`" ...` might be required.

Comment: Thank you all, its actually the first time I need to use the shell, so I thought may be don't know some important commands.

Comment: actually $'\t' is the only way I can express tab, may be that's because I use mac, not linux.

Comment: @tmac_balla: On a Mac, the default shell is `bash` (`bash 3.2.51` as of OS X 10.9.2), which does support escape sequences via `$'...'` -- e.g., `$\t'`, as you've discovered -- a.k.a. _ANSI-C quoting_ - see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting. @ghoti's suggestion should work on ALL Bourne-like shells, including POSIX-only shells (ANSI-C quoting is not part of the POSIX standard): `"$(printf '\t')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't save characters, but you can eliminate the initial cut if you sort and uniq -c by field:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k2 file.txt | uniq -f2 -s1 -c
```

That at least removes a command from the chain.  You could also combine the last head and cut with a simple awk one-liner:

```
awk '{if(NR<11)print $3}'
```

This is both longer and less simple, but again saves a command.

Comment: Well, you can shave off a whopping 7 chars. by using `awk 'NR<11&&$0=$3'` :) Curiously, though, on OS X 10.9.2 there appears to be a bug, the workaround for which, sadly, adds back 2 chars: `awk 'NR<11&&$0=$3""'`

Comment: Also, you can save another 4 chars. by omitting `-s1 ` from the `uniq` command (all it does is to exclude the `\t` that precedes the field value of interest from the comparison, right?).

Comment: You're right.  I had the -s option wrong.  I thought it would skip n trailing fields, similar to how -f skips leading fields.  Upon review of the man page, not correct.  It looks like you cannot ignore trailing fields with uniq.

Comment: Yes, `uniq` is a strange duck: both `-f` (fields) and `-s` (chars. in field) specify what to _ignore_, _from the beginning_, and the definition of a field _includes the preceding separator(s)_.